# (VBA-Excel) My "EntireRow.Delete" delete all my rows instead of one line/row, why?

Tags: vba, excel

First of forgiveness if it is a duplicate topic, I look but maybe not as it should ...
I'm not good in english.

Then I'll explain my problem, I'm trying to write a macro vba for excel.

This macro executes with a button click ('chargement_des_donnees()').

1) It empties my sheet "Detail SO in process", except the first line,
2) Then, executes a sql query IBM and copy my be the score sheet clean.
3) Processes my data:
                - Deletes the second line corresponding to the headings of my query,
                - Recovers some values to put in my "sheet1"
                - Actualise my dynamic crosstab my "sheet1".

**The problem is that when I try to remove my second line of my sheet "Detail SO in process", everything is deleted (except the first line).
When I use the 'Debug' it works properly.**

I feel that my "EntireRow.Delete" loops.

My code :

```
Sub refresh_sql()     

    Sheets("Detail SO in process").Select        
    sqlstring = "my request"        
    connstring = _
        "ODBC;DSN=HSDAS6 - SITEWWCS;UID=poiriet;"
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, _
            Destination:=Range("A2"), Sql:=sqlstring)
        .Refresh
    End With

    Worksheets("Detail SO in process").Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete   
End Sub
```

Please help me, explain me.

Thanks to advise.

Comment: I would recommend to narrow down your question and delete the irrelevant part of the code. The only real issue under consideration is EntireRow.Delete in a Loop. Thanks and regards,

Comment: ok, it's done, I hope it's better like that?

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to your edited post, the answer to your question in regards to EntireRow.Delete follow.

1. You can try to use this one:

   Sub refresh_sql()

   ```
   Sheets("Detail SO in process").Select        
   sqlstring = "my request"        
   connstring = _
       "ODBC;DSN=HSDAS6 - SITEWWCS;UID=poiriet;"
   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, _
           Destination:=Range("A2"), Sql:=sqlstring)
       .Refresh
   End With

   Worksheets("Detail SO in process").Range("A2").EntireRow.Delete
   ```

   End Sub

You also can use row deletion as shown below:

```
Sub refresh_sql()     

    'YOUR OTHER CODE

    Worksheets("Detail SO in process").Rows(2).Delete   
End Sub
```

Both statements perform the same action of deleting the second row (entirely) in Excel Worksheet and shifting up the rest.

Note: if you still experience the same problem, check the other part of your code. The row deletion statement itself works properly.

Hope this will help.

Comment: You should also correct it in another Sub() with looping. Best regards,

Comment: No, the Sub nettoyer_page() is to clean my sheet(I know is not the very good method but I need to keep my first row), it's in my Sub mise_en_page() that I have problem ...

Comment: The answer was given to you: the loop is causing the problem. Please accept the answer, and if you have another question, post it separately. Best regards,

Comment: Most likely, your other code is causing the problem. The row deletion works just fine. Regards,

Comment: I remove my other code and it doesn't work ! I know normally it should work but it is not.